# Using async methods in one branch of match

Tags: f#

I'm getting started with F# and async.

I have trying to convert some C# code that looks like:

```
public async Task<string> getValueOrDefault(string? key)
{
  if (key is null)
  {
    return "default";
  }
  else
  {
    return await getValue(key);
  }
}
```

My F# code looks like:

```
    let getValueOrDefault (key: Option<string>) =
        async {
            return match key with
            | None -> "default"
            | Some (key) -> getValue key
        }
```

It complains that the 2 branches have different types: `string` and `Async<string>`.
Changing `return` to `return!` of course tells me that `"default"` is expected to be `Async<'a>`

I can do:

```
    let getValueOrDefault (key: Option<string>) =
        async {
            return! match key with
                    | None -> async { return "default" }
                    | Some (key) -> getValue key
        }
```

But is this the "right" way of doing it? Does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the equivalent of the `await` keyword in your first F# version which is `let!` or `return!`.

I think your second version is perfectly adequate, but you can also do this, where each of the match results returns its own value.

```
    let getValueOrDefault (key: Option<string>) =
        async {
            match key with
            | None -> return "default"
            | Some (key) -> return! getValue key
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. For some reason it didn't occur to me that I could have the two different return versions inside the match

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write this the way Tim does in his answer, i.e. wrap the whole method in an `async { .. }` block and then use `return` in one branch and `return!` in the other. However, you can also simplify your last snippet a bit by turning `async { return! e }` to just `e` - because that's exactly equivalent.

Then you get another quite elegant version, which also encodes the same logic:

```
let getValueOrDefault (key: Option<string>) =
    match key with
    | None -> async { return "default" }
    | Some (key) -> getValue key
```

Comment: Or even `let getValueOrDefault = function None -> async { return "default" }| Some (key) -> getValue key`

Comment: That is a nice simplification of my second version!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really wrong with your attempt, except that the double computational expressions look a bit weird.
You can easily avoid that by calling getValue outside your `async {}`

How about this:

```
let getValueOrDefault (key:string option) =
    key 
    |> Option.map getValue
    |> Option.defaultValue (async { return "default"})
```